# Filter Convoloution Java - how it works?

Tags: java, bufferedimage, graphics2d

I'm making an application that applies some filters to a loaded image on java..

I'm stuck where i create a compatible buffered image, get the graphics2d object and render my new image..

This is my code where i create the BufferedImage compatible..

```
pbi=obi.getSubimage(0, 0, obi.getWidth(),obi.getHeight());
            int altoImagen=pbi.getHeight();
            int anchoImagen=pbi.getWidth();
            pbi=new BufferedImage(anchoImagen,altoImagen,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            g2=pbi.createGraphics();
```

After that i apply the filter on obi OriginalBufferedImage  with the original image..

```
float ninth=1.0f/9.0f;
        float[]blurKernel={
            ninth,ninth,ninth,
            ninth,ninth,ninth,
            ninth,ninth,ninth
        };
        ConvolveOp op=new ConvolveOp(new Kernel(3,3,blurKernel));
        obi=op.filter(obi,null);    
        lienzo.repaint();
        g2.drawImage(obi, null,null);
```

The problem, and i can figure what is.. is that the new image is not rendered..

i think that happend when i do `g2=pbi.createGraphics` .. But on many tutorials that step must be done..

Someone can explain me exactly how the rendering works?..

I'm not using components, instead i'm using Graphics2d.drawImage() to render images (and graphics) into a JPanel.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? When you write `obi = op.filter(obi,null)` you are already creating the filtered image; there is no need to draw it on a third image.

Comment: .yeah just noticed that .. you know.. i'm basing my project on a tutorial made by my instructor... And i just have noticing that haves many errors ..